# A compound adjective with a double noun: where does the hyphen go?

Tags: meaning, hyphenation

I have a noun that consists of two words ("impact parameter") that I am trying to turn into a compound adjective to describe a certain type of collision ("high impact parameter collision").  Where, if anywhere, should the hyphens go on this phrase?  The two choices I can't decide between are:

- high-impact parameter collision
- high-impact-parameter collision

Answer (score 0):

There may be some obscure rule for this, but if I were you, I'd trust my intuition a tiny bit more.

"High" here modifies "impact," not "parameter." However, this only becomes manifest if you join them together by using a hyphen.

That said, yet another hyphen would negate the effect, rendering the meaning of the phrase vague once again.

I would therefore vote for

> high-impact parameter collision

I hope this helps.

Comment: high modifies "impact parameter".  I'm not talking about parameters with high impact, I'm talking about collisions with high impact parameters.  "Impact parameter" refers to one idea.

Comment: @Joshua I think that's only clear if you go with "high impact-parameter collision".  Leave the noun as a compound noun and don't hyphenate to make the adjective. An alternative for academic writing is to define a new term or acronym once, clearly, then only use that.  Going with "high-IP collision" might resolve the concern while preserving readability.

Comment: @Joshua: Whatever floats your boat, dude!

Answer (score 0):

Does the parameter collision have high impact?

- I might use *high-impact parameter-collision*

Or do the parameters have high impact and they then collide?

- I might use *high-impact-parameter collision*

Or is the impact parameter collision high?

- I might use *high impact-parameter-collision*

Or are the impact parameters high and they then collide?

- I might use *high impact-parameter collision*

A lot of this comes from personal preference. Perhaps it should all be rephrased for greater clarity

Comment: Yes; stacking modifiers quickly leads to inevitable clunkiness and frequent ambiguities.

Comment: The planets have an impact parameter that is high when they collide.